# Arch Linux - pacman givers error 'could not resolve host'

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, pacman

I just installed Arch Linux and I'm trying to set up my wifi. I'm trying to run `pacman -U` to install some files I have off a USB stick, namely `wpa-supplicant`. When I run the command, I get a long line of errors that all say something along the lines of `failed retrieving file ... Could not resolve host`

Comment: Give full command.

Comment: @TuyenPham `pacman -U /mnt/wpa_supplicant-2_2.6-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Comment: When you install a package, if it has dependencies that require to install first, you have to manually install them first, the above error is that pacman try to install some dependencies from internet. Check your package and install its required packages.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, are you connected via cable? Can you try pinging 1.1.1.1 and google.com and post the results here?

Comment: First, do: `pacman -Qo wifi-menu`, then do `pacman -Qi netctl` and then go ahead and download all these packages (manually from [package site](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/netctl/) or by doing `pacman -Syuw --cachedir /tmp/cache_download --database /tmp netctl` and grab all `*.xz*` files from `/tmp/cache_download`). Bring those over to your machine and install them in some form of correct order. Replace this process for any package you want, for instance - `wpa_supplicant`. You can also create a [local mirror](http://tiny.cc/ne7k2y) on the USB drive.

Comment: @Yaron when I ping www.google.com I get `Temporary failure in name resolution` and when I ping 1.1.1.1 I get `connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Check this guide `https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant`, make sure to generate wifi profile correctly. You should install wpa_supplicant at the time that you install arch, otherwise you don't have necessary means to make wifi works. `pacstrap /mnt base base-devel wpa_supplicant` - check installation guide.